# Help with RAM speeds? and Is dual Channel worth it?

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

I ran crucial's diagnostic software and it says I only have 2GB of ram on my laptop. It says I can have up to 8GB of ram and that I have 1 free slot. So I will buy like another 2GB stick or maybe 4GB stick.

However it also says that the laptop supports dual channel memory. Do I really need to bother with that and buy a pair? It says that each memory slot can hold DDR3 PC3-8500, DDR3 PC3-10600 with a maximum of 4GB per slot.

However it also doesn't say if my current ram is 8500 or 10600... I'm guessing 10600 is faster. Is that correct?

I'm worried about mixing and matching the wrong ram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your ram will work at the speed of the slowest ram you have - if you have 8500, ALL your ram will run as 8500 (you can check ram speed with WMIC - in a command prompt wmic MEMORYCHIP get speed will give you the speed.)

Dual channel memory gives a slight boost with matched ram, BUT more ram is generally better than matched ram - 4gb of matched ram works better than 4gb of non matched ram, but not better than say, 6 gb of unmatched ram  you can either change both your sticks of ram (to 8gb) with a kit (which sometimes is cheaper than buying the two sticks seperatedly) or add a stick of ram (to up to 6 gb). Just remember to get SODIMM ram, or whatever your laptop uses.

Comment: Also, if you are going above 4 GB total, make sure you are using 64-bit architecture, as 32-bit architecture won't use more than 4 GB.

Comment: cpu-z says DRAM freq 532 Mhz... so which ram should i get 8500 or 10600? Thanks. And that freq seems very slow... :(

Comment: Isn't most ddr3 minimum of like 1333 Mhz?

Comment: dram freq != ram speed on DDR is roughly twice as fast as dram freq - SIW shows dram freq of 332.5 mhz (as does cpuz) and speed of 667 mhz - with ddr2 ram.

Comment: so what speed is my ram running at? it is ddr3

Comment: use speccy or SIW to check. Its more likely 10600 tho. CPU-Z just isn't giving the *right* information.

Comment: speccy also says DRAM is 552...... so i have no idea what freq it is running at.

Comment: hm. SIW gives both 'dram frequency' and 'speed' for me. speccy dosen't seem to, nor does cpu-z - both give dram frequency. Give SIW a shot - its what i usually use.

Comment: SIW site won't load for me... not sure why but i am in China, could be firewall thing.

Comment: hmm, try opening up cmd.exe and 'wmic MEMORYCHIP get speed'

Comment: ok that says 1067. This seems slow for ddr3 is it not? cpu-z says it is ddr3 10700.

Comment: 1067 mhz sounds sensible/realistic.

Comment: so if i go to media market and buy a 4gb chip of ddr3 1333hz, then it will downclock to 1067? cry.

Comment: yes. it'll still be an improvement over what you have now. You always have the option of replacing all your ram ;). Ram has ALWAYS worked this way.  Considering the question was answered, you might want to select this as the right answer ;).

Comment: my bios is rediculous... just took a peak and no option about ram at all... it just tells you what you have with no ability to tweak anything. Sigh.